# MySQL Insert Query Doesn't Work (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I need help in understanding why my simple insert query doesn't work.

**the code below:**

```
<?php

// db info
define ( 'DB_HOST', '' );`enter code here`
define ( 'DB_USER', '' );
define ( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' );
define ( 'DB_NAME', '' );

create_db_connection ();
function create_db_connection() {
    global $con;

    $con = mysql_connect ( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD ) or die ( "connection not established" );
    $db = mysql_select_db ( DB_NAME, $con ) or die ( "database not connected" );
}


$sql= "insert into 'tbl_BonAproval' (OrderId,RestId) values (20001,98765)";


if (mysqli_query ( $db, $sql )) {
    echo "Successfully inserted " . mysqli_affected_rows ( $db ) . " row";
} else {
    echo "Error occurred: " . mysqli_error ( $db );
}
function close_mysql_connection() {
    global $con;
    mysql_close ( $con );
}

$result = mysql_query ( "SELECT * FROM `tbl_BonAproval`" );
$row = mysql_fetch_array ( $result );
print_r ( $row ); // print array
echo $row ['table field name']; // print field data

// $sql=mysql_query('INSERT INTO tbl_BonAproval (OrderId, RestId) VALUES (24553, 01001);');
                               // echo $sql;



mysql_close ( $conn );
class CallBack {
}

?>
```

Comment: The `INSERT` does not work because the Tablename was wrapped with single quotes. **Remove the single quotes around the table name and it will work**. Single quotes are used for string literals and not with identifiers such as column names and table names. When table names happen to be a reserved keyword, it must be escaped with backticks, not with single quotes.

Comment: why `mysqli_query` ?? change to `mysql_query`

Comment: @swapnesh how do you ground that argument? `mysql_query()` is deprecated, the manual cleary discourages its usage. The officially suggested replacement is the newer `mysqli` extension. Instead, all of the other `mysql_*()` function calls should be changed to `mysqli_*()`

Answer (score 5):

You should try ***MySQLi*** instead of its predecessor ***MySQL***. Here's a simplified code of yours:

```
<?php

$conn=mysqli_connect("YourHost","YourUsername","YourPassword","YourDatabase");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO tbl_BonAproval (OrderId, RestId) VALUES ('20001','98765')");

$result = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_BonAproval");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)){
echo $row['table field name']; /* print field data */ 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't mix `mysql` and `mysqli`. In order to use `mysqli` you should open a `mysqli` connection. And use back ticks for table name in insert query.

EG:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('HOST', 'USERNAME', 'PASS', 'TABLE'); //use mysqli connection

$sql= "insert into `tbl_BonAproval` (OrderId,RestId) values ('20001','98765')"; //for insert query
```

Sidenote: `mysql_*` is deprecated, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 2):

Change the insert query to this:

```
$sql= "insert into `tbl_BonAproval` (OrderId,RestId) values (20001,98765)";
```

You can't use single quotes to encapsulate the table or column names.